# Issues with AJAX GET to PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to delete a post and sending the ID value to a PHP file which deletes the post through a prepared statement query..

I am sending the ID value as following, and the jQuery works and registers the ID value properly (have tested with console.log)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#delete-btn").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-value");
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET",
       data: {id: id},
       url: "../php/delete-user.php",
       success: function(){
           $(this).val("");
           parent.slideUp("fast");
           console.log(id);
       }});
})
</script>
```

So i figure the issue is within the PHP file, which it seem to be finding by the correct url, if i change the current url the code doesn't reach the "success" point in the code, which makes me think that is not the issue.

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php")
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo mysqli_error($conn);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

What i can see with my newbie eyes, there is no coding issue, and the connect.php is properly linked, so what can the issue lye on here?

Comment: Try calling the php file from a browser with the proper parameters and see what it returns. If you're not seeing the success hit in your JS, the the AJAX call may be failing. You may have to add a fail handler to your AJAX call.

Comment: To call from a browser, you may have to modify the php script and use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET.

Comment: The `success` block is not reached at, but is the record getting deleted from the table for the `id` passed by jQuery?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `method:` option was added in 1.9, older versions use `type:`.

Comment: The record is not getting deleted. Im using 3.1.1.

Comment: I have basically used the exact same script on another spot on my page, where it works perfectly with the $_GET['id']

Comment: @Dhruv Saxena The success block IS reached, but record is not deleted

Comment: Does it delete the record if the program is executed directly using the URL: `delete-user.php?id=99`?

Comment: I'd just also want to point out (though it might just be a typo) that a semicolon is missing after `include("connect.php")`

Comment: @Dhruv Saxena Fixed it, i'll accept your answer if you make one. Sometimes the simplest things.

Answer (score 0):

Since your id might be an int, try using "i" to bind your param i.e.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only a small fix and the error may have just been typographical. However, the reason why the PHP code, despite being invoked properly by AJAX, didn't delete any record from the table is most probably because the code's execution would have ended abruptly due to a syntax error:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    // include("connect.php")           //---> Missing semicolon; syntax error
    include("connect.php");             //---> Fixed
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    ..
    ..
?>
```